# Blender Bevel Object scale issues corners

Tags: bezier-curves

This is bothering me for some time in Blender. It would be excellent if this could work, especially for archviz. Anyone knows is there some workaround to fix this issue, when using bevel object on curve there are scaling issues on corners or ends (not sure where issue is)? Handle types are Vectors.

Attached image.

[image]

Comment: OK found solution myself, should just use 2D instead of 3D. It covers 80% cases so I can call it good.

Comment: You can increase resolution of the bevel object if you mean changing of the sharp corners. The more subdivided bevel object is, the more smooth beveled curve will be (and polycount will grow too)

Answer (score 1):

You can control the radius of each segment of the curve separately:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found solution myself, should just use 2D instead of 3D. It covers 80% cases so I can call it good.